# RSS to HTML script - version two

Tags: python, html, parsing, rss

I wrote this script that downloads an RSS feed and converts it to HTML. One of my only concerns is my variable naming because I suck at naming things.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Simple RSS to HTML converter."""

__version__ = "0.0.2"
__author__ = "Ricky L Wilson"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from feedparser import parse as parse_feed


TEMPLATE = u"""
<h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
<a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
<span class='description'>{summary}</span>
"""

def entry_to_html(**kwargs):
    """Formats feedparser entry."""
    return TEMPLATE.format(**kwargs).encode('utf-8')


def convert_feed(url):
    """Main loop."""
    html_fragments = [entry_to_html(**entry) for entry in parse_feed(url).entries]
    return BeautifulSoup("\n".join(html_fragments), 'lxml').prettify()


def save_file(url, filename):
    """Saves data to disc."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(convert_feed(url).encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
    with open('index.html') as fobj:
        print fobj.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### About the generated HTML

Each feed item should become an [`article`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-article-element). This would also allow you to include the generated HTML on any page without having to adjust the heading levels. Unless you know that `h2` would always be the correct heading element in your case, you might want to use `h1` instead.

You could give the `a` element the [`bookmark`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#link-type-bookmark) link type.

Unless you remove markup from the feed item’s description, you might want to use a `div` instead of a `span`, because a `span` can’t contain many elements that might appear in the description.

You could specify a class on the `article` element, and omit the classes on its child elements. Less potential to conflict with classes that might already be used in the document.

```html
<article class='feed-item'>
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <a href='{link}' rel='bookmark'>{title}</a>
  <div>{summary}</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use a `Mako` template engine, you need to first install it:

```
pip install Mako
```

Then, create a template HTML file that you will render on the fly, `template.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        % for feed in feeds:
            <div>
                <h2 class='title'>${feed.title}</h2>
                <a class='link' href='${feed.link}'>${feed.title}</a>
                <span class='description'>${feed.summary}</span>
            </div>
        % endfor
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, you need to render this HTML file with the context of your feeds:

```
from feedparser import parse as parse_feed

from mako.template import Template


def convert_feed(url, filename):
    """Convert feed to an HTML."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        html_content = Template(filename='template.html', output_encoding='utf-8').render(feeds=parse_feed(url).entries)
        file_object.write(html_content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert_feed('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
```